# Natural Sort of list containing paths in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, sorting, path

I have a list `paths_list` which contains the path of files(images) of a particular folder . Example:

```
['/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg', 
'/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg', 
'/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg', 
'/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg', 
'/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg', 
'/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg']
```

I want to sort then in the order: `[/1.jpg ,2.jpg .....,/12.jpg]`
Neither sorting via **length** nor via **alphabetical** order is helping. What should be done here?

Comment: so **how** do you want to sort? what is the rule? if there is a rule it can be done.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `sorted` with a `lambda`. For the sorting criteria, you can use `os` to first pull just the file name (using [`basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)), then you can split off just the filename less the extension (using [`splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)).

Lastly convert to `int` so you sort numerically instead of lexicographically.

```
>>> import os
>>> l = ['/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda i: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0]))
['/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg']
```

Comment: is there a reason for replacing the `split('.')` with `splitext`? Multiple dots in the basename?

Comment: I just figured since I was already using `os` for `basename` I'd use `splitext` to make it more clear what that split was doing. `split('.')` would have worked just fine too. Yeah that is also a good catch, `splitext` will work properly for multiple dots in the filename too, although not in this particular case, since they want the value to be numbers they can sort numerically.

Comment: I guess you should also add the point that unlike `.sort()` , `sorted()` doesn't sort the list in place so we need to save the list . for example :
`l = sorted(l, key=lambda i: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0]))`

Answer (score 13):

Use natural sorting (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)): clean code and good practice when sorting strings.

```
from natsort import natsorted
l = ['/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg']
natsorted(l)
```

gives

```
['/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg',
'/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg']
```

Natural sorting sorts based on how you would read things on a computer screen (alphabetically and numerically), rather than how the computer reads the code.

Comment: I guess `natsorted` doesn't sort the list in place and we need to save the sorted list to some new list.

Comment: That is correct. It is also true for all other answers that use `sorted()`

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @Cory Kramer's answer, you can use the `pathlib` library and get a natural sort of the paths:

```
from pathlib import Path

a = ['/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', 
     '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg']

a = [Path(i) for i in a]
sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda i: int(i.stem))
sorted_a = [str(i) for i in a]
```

output:

```
['/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg']
```

In general, using `pathlib` can sometimes give cleaner code expressions than plane `os.path`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split on "/", take the last element, split on ".", take the first, and convert it too an int:

```
l = ['/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg']
sorted_list = sorted(l, key = lambda x: int(x.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]))
```

output

```
['/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg']
```

Comment: I guess you should also add the point that unlike `.sort()` , `sorted()` doesn't sort the list in place so we need to save the list . for example :
`l = sorted(l, key=lambda i: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0]))`

Comment: @Varun Thanks, didn't think about that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are good. But anyhow I would like to post mine with some explanations

```
from os.path import basename,splitext
path_list = ['/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg',
             '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg',
             '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg',
             '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg',
             '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg',
             '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg']

new_list = [splitext(basename(x))[0] for x in path_list]

fin_list = list(zip(path_list,new_list))

fin_list = [x[0] for x in sorted(fin_list,key=lambda x: int(x[1]))]

print(fin_list)
```

1) Creates a list which has only the file name. `1,2,..` and so on.

```
new_list = [splitext(basename(x))[0] for x in path_list]
```

**Note:** Why [0] ?? Because the output of each `splitext(basename(x))[0]` would be like this,

```
('1','.jpg') , ('4','.jpg')
```

so `[0] 0th` index gives us just the filename!

2) **zip** each and every item from both iterables with each other and create a list. So this list has values like these,

```
fin_list = list(zip(path_list,new_list))
#output
('/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg','4.jpg')
```

3) `[x[0] for x in sorted(fin_list,key=lambda x: int(x[1]))]`

This one creates a list from the sorted list of `fin_list` note **key** is the main thing here. Key will be the second item from tuple i.e `4,3,7,..` and such. Based  on which sorting happens.

finally your **output**:

```
['/home/username/images/s1/1.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/2.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/3.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/4.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/5.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/6.jpg', 
'/home/username/images/s1/7.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/8.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/9.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/10.jpg',
 '/home/username/images/s1/11.jpg', '/home/username/images/s1/12.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this neat

```
from pathlib import Path  # pathlib comes with python
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda image_path: Path(image_path).name)
```

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of Shir's answer, if your file names are version numbers such as `1.0.ext`, `2.3.4.ext`, `3.0.ext`, you can use:

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

files = Path('/your/path/here').glob('*.ext')

files = [
    f for f in files
    if re.match("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*", f.stem)
]

files = sorted(
    files,
    key=lambda s: [int(u) for u in s.stem.split('.')]
)
```